# How To Get The Value After A Certain Character in PHP and RegEX?

Tags: php, regex

How do I get the value after a certain character ( '@' in my case) in a string? I have this code, but its not working;
There will be only alphanumeric characters and/or space.

```
$data = 'Someone @Will Be There';

preg_match ("/@([a-zA-Z0-9 ]*)/", $data, $match);
return $match [0];
```

All I want to get that "Will Be There" if that @ is present in the string.
Thanks

**Edit:** Extremely sorry for my mistake. I don't wanna remove that '@', I need to get What are ***After*** that. Sorry again, people.

Comment: http://php.net/strpos and http://php.net/strstr

Comment: @Abhik Changed my code to reflect your changes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first group is in `$match[1]`, not in `$match[0]`

Change your code to:

```
$data = 'Someone @Will Be There';
preg_match ("/@([a-zA-Z0-9 ]*)/", $data, $match);
return $match[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Changed my code to reflect your changes...

```
$data = 'Someone @Will Be There';
$character = '@';

if ($string = stringAfterCharacter($data, $character)){
    echo $string;
}else{
    echo "Character: '$character' not found.";
}


function stringAfterCharacter($data, $character='@'){
    if (($pos = strpos($data, $character)) !== false){
        return substr($data, $pos + 1);
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `strpos()` for that purpose. It searches for a substring - or at least a char - in a string and the returns the first position of that substring.

```
$position = strpos('I am @ the penthouse', '@');
```

When the substring was not found in the string the method returns false.

There are common pitfalls that come with `strpos()` in php. Check the following example :

```
if(!strpos('@stackoverflow', '@')) {
  echo 'the string contains no @';
 }
```

The would output that '@' was not found although the string contains an at. Thats because of the weak data typing in PHP. The previous `strpos()` call will return int(0) because it is the first char in string. But this will make the if fail unless you do :

```
if(strpos('@stackoverflow', '@') === FALSE) {
   echo 'the string contains no @';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better can use simple string replacement method and try this,

```
$data = 'Someone @Will Be There';
$result = str_replace('@','',$data); // result is: Someone Will Be There
```

Don't Use this:

```
//preg_match ("/@([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/", $data, $match);
//return $match [0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use regex, which generally is slow, to do that. Just do:
return str_replace('@', '', $data);

Answer (score 0):

This will remove any symbols from the string

```
$data = 'Someone @Will Be There';
echo preg_replace("/([^A-Za-z0-9 ]*)/", '', $data); //Add character in the pattern if not to be filtered
```

**Output:**

```
Someone Will Be There
```

Answer (score 0):

You question seems ambiguous, If you want to remove '@' from the string, then you can use the answers with str_replace.
If you want the value after '@' you should check for $match[1] in your own code.